# Auth from aws-amplify is undefined in Nextjs app

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I'm unable to import `Auth` from `aws-amplify` (same for `aws-amplify/auth`).  As a simple example, if I just try to load `Auth` in _app.js (before any other pages load), it returns undefined in the browser console:

```
// src/pages/_app.js
import '../../styles/globals.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import Script from 'next/script';
import config from '../aws-exports';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(config);
console.log('auth: ', Auth);

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aabf17dcb4.js" strategy="afterInteractive" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

This happens in any page I try to load; the rest of my Amplify setup and Nextjs pages render and function as expected.  The actual authentication (via Amplify/Cognito/Google SSO) works when I use Authenticator from `aws-amplify/ui-react`.  It's just the `Auth` component that won't load.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sessionreviewapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^6.0.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.0.4",
    "axios": "^1.6.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "next": "^12.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.9.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.37",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried importing with and without { } around Auth, resetting node_modules, re-building the app locally, and have dug around in a bunch of Github issues, but so far I haven't been able to figure out what is going wrong.  Kind of a hair puller - any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V6 looks different to the V5 way you're doing it:

```
import { signIn, type SignInInput } from 'aws-amplify/auth';

async function handleSignIn({ username, password }: SignInInput) {
  try {
    const { isSignedIn, nextStep } = await signIn({ username, password });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error signing in', error);
  }
}
```

https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/enable-sign-up/

Comment: So exactly what I needed, thank you!